# Using Microsoft.Graph Calendar View Sensitivity field only returning Normal

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft.Graph Calendar View with meeting id the sensitivity field only returning Normal.

MS Graph API Call:
https://someIp:443/microsoft-graph-api/v1/users/pd.team.room.ls2521@abc.com/calendarView?startDateTime=2018-07-17&endDateTime=2018-07-18

Response:
     "sensitivity": "normal",  Instead of  “Private”

Comment: did you found a solution for this?? I'm having the same issue